# How to capture form values and send them via email as ajax request ? Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, django, forms

I'm trying to setup a simple form where the user types in his email address to subscribe for a newsletter. I then receive an email with the user's email address.

This is what I tried so far:

*The form:*

```
<%= form_for :subscribe, id: 'sub_form' do |f| %>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" id="sub_email">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="sub_btn">Subscribe</button><br>
    <p id="sub_output" class="lead" style="color: white;"></p>
<% end %>
```

*The route*

```
  post 'subscribe/:email', :to => 'welcome3#subscribe', as: "email_subscribtion"
```

*The controller:*

```
class Welcome3Controller < ApplicationController
  def subscribe
    EmailMeMailer.confirmation().deliver
  end
end
```

*The mailer:*

```
class EmailMeMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "info@example.com"

  def confirmation
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "my_email_address@gmail.com", subject: "subscribtion confirmation"
  end
end
```

*JQuery Ajax method:*

```
$('#sub_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }).validate({ 
    rules: {

      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },

    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {

      var btn = $('#sub_btn');
      btn.button('loading');
      setTimeout(function() {
        btn.button('reset');
      }, 3000);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/subscribe',
        // data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: {
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
          sub_email: $('#sub_email').val(),
        },

        success: function (json) {

          $('#sub_output').html(json.message);
          $("#sub_email").prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });

         return false; // for demo
     } 
 });
```

I'm stuck at: how do I capture the submitted email address and send it to myself ? I'm not using any models to save data. Also, according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OI-m0wbmf8A&t=206s) tutorial, Mailer does not have access to the POST request.

Bear in mind that I'm converting a Django app to RoR so that I can deploy it on cPanel. You can see the Django app [here](https://payligent.pythonanywhere.com/): the form is in the footer.

*This is the view:*

```
<h1>Welcome3#subscribe</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome3/subscribe.html.erb</p>
```

EDIT:

Also, in my Django app I send to this url:

```
url: '/subscribe/'

data: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
    email: $('#sub_email').val(),
    },
```

How should this be different in Rails ?

This is the JQuery Ajax request together

```
submitHandler: function (form) {

    var btn = $('#sub_btn');
    btn.button('loading');
    setTimeout(function() {
      btn.button('reset');
    }, 3000);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/subscribe/',
      // data: form.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
        email: $('#sub_email').val(),
      },

      success: function (json) {

        $('#sub_output').html("Thanks");
        $("#sub_email").prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });

       return false;
    }
```

EDIT 2:

At this stage when I click on the subscribe button, I receive this routing error:

> Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/"
>
> Rails.root: C:/Sites/payligent
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace Routes
>
> Routes match in priority from top to bottom
>
> Helper    HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action Path / Url         Path Match
>   root_path GET /    welcome#index
>
> package_signup_path   GET /pricing/:level(.:format)    welcome2#pricing
>
> email_subscribtion_path   GET /subscribe/:email(.:format) 
>   welcome3#subscribe

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get post data inside the controller, and pass it as an argument to the mailer action.

EDIT: The solution above worked here.

#### HTML:

```
<%= form_for :subscribe, html: { id: 'sub_form' } do |f| %>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" id="sub_email">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="sub_btn">Subscribe</button><br>
  <p id="sub_output" class="lead" style="color: white;"></p>
<% end %>
```

#### Javascript:

```
<script>
$('#sub_form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/subscribe',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
        sub_email: $('#sub_email').val(),
      },
      success: function (json) {
        $('#sub_output').html(json.message);
        $("#sub_email").prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
});
</script>
```

#### Controller (app/controllers/welcome3_controller.rb)

```
class Welcome3Controller < ApplicationController
  def subscribe
    EmailMeMailer.confirmation(params[:sub_email]).deliver_now

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

PS: The `.deliver` method was [deprecated](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/deliver/class) after v2.3.8. You should use `.deliver_now` instead of it.

#### Mailer: (app/mailers/email_me_mailer.rb)

```
class EmailMeMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "info@example.com"

  def confirmation(email)
    @greeting = "Hi"
    @email = email

    mail to: "my_email_address@gmail.com", subject: "subscribtion confirmation"
  end
end
```

#### Mailer View: (app/mailers/email_me_mailer.rb)

```
Email: <%= @email %>
```

#### Routes: (config/routes.rb)

```
post '/subscribe' => 'welcome3#subscribe'
```

PS:

1) Don't forget to generate mailer layout on 
`app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb`.

2) Remember that the extension of layout and view depends on what type of content-type you defined in the mailer. If is text (default), the file you have extension `.text.erb`, and if is HTML the file will have `.html.erb`.

Comment: Thanks! however, at which stage am I reading the sub_email I passed in the data dict. Also I need to email it to my own email address not the user's (I need to email myself the user's email address).

Comment: Hey mate, after call mail action passing email parameter, you can set it as a local variable. So it will be visible in the view context. I did an update to the example. Look if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you. At this stage I receive a routing error when clicking the submit button. I believe it should be something in the ajax request. What should the 'url' and 'data' look like ?

Comment: I need a little more information to understand what is going wrong. Can you show the HTML with the subscription form and who calls `submitHandler` ?

Comment: I saw something strange here. You are doing an ajax request in your javascript, and there are no routes defined for this method in `routes.rb`. Create a route to the URI `/subscribe` with method post, pointing to `welcome3#subscribe`. If it doesn't solve the problem, show me HTML. The problem can be there.

Comment: I changed the request from get to post, still receive the error. The html is already in the question under 'the form'. the ajax is triggered once the form with a specific id is submitted: $('#sub_form').submit(function(e) {

Comment: I think the problem is related with the trigger event `.submit`. If you are using AJAX to send email data, you cannot let the form submit. The route error you got ("no route matches [POST]") probably happened because you form was submited to action="/". This explains the error . I will update my question with a solution. Wait a minute, bro.

Comment: @Seio, updated the answer. Take a look in the steps i placed there. See if it will solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150516/discussion-between-gabriel-gomes-and-seio).