# Rails ajax form sends emails but doesn't run the code under "success"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, post

I'm very new to Rails but I managed to put together a form that sends me an email upon submit thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395743/how-to-capture-form-values-and-send-them-via-email-as-ajax-request-rails/45395772#45395772) answer, but it doesn't run the code in the success section.

This is the JQuery Ajax code:

```
$('#sub_form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {

     var btn = $('#sub_btn');
    btn.button('loading');
    setTimeout(function() {
      btn.button('reset');
    }, 3000);


    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/subscribe',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      data: {

        sub_email: $('#sub_email').val(),
      },
      success: function (json) {
        $('#sub_output').html("Thank you!");
        $("#sub_email").prop('disabled', true);
      },

    });

    return false;
  }
});
```

This is the controller:

```
class Welcome3Controller < ApplicationController
  def subscribe
    EmailMeMailer.confirmation(params[:sub_email]).deliver_now

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

This is the form:

```
<%= form_for :subscribe, html: { id: 'sub_form' } do |f| %>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" id="sub_email">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="sub_btn">Subscribe</button><br>
  <p id="sub_output" class="lead" style="color: white;"></p>
<% end %>
```

When the form is posted I receive an email fine but it doesn't run the success code (for ex it doesn't output "Thank you!")

Comment: add :remote => true to form_for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get reach success callback in your AJAX, you need to have a valid json and also return status code `200`.

Try to put this in your controller:

```
render json: { success: true }, status: 200
```

Your code will look like this:

```
class Welcome3Controller < ApplicationController
  def subscribe
    EmailMeMailer.confirmation(params[:sub_email]).deliver_now

    render json: { success: true }, status: 200
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
:remote=> true
```

to form_for, and :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

to controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are requesting a JSON response, use `head :no_content` instead of [`head :ok`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1742)

```
def subscribe
  EmailMeMailer.confirmation(params[:sub_email]).deliver_now

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```